# python text splitter program

Tags: python, file-io

I have a program that splits a text into sentences using the following rule:

Sentence boundaries occur at ".", "?" and "!" except:

A) Periods followed by digit with no intervening whitespaces.  B) Periods followed by whitespaces followed by lower case letters.  C) Periods with no followed whitespaces.  D) Periods preceded with titles.

My written code is as given below:

```
file_name = raw_input("Enter the name of the text file: ")
txt_file = open('%s.txt' % file_name, 'r+')
text = txt_file.readline()
print; print "Original text is: "; print
print text

new_wrd = []
new_line = []
new_txt = []

while len(text.strip()) != 0:
    for index, char in enumerate(text):
        print char
        if char == "." or char == "?" or char == "!":
            if text[index+1] == " ":

                if ("".join(new_wrd) == "Mrs" or "".join(new_wrd) == "Mr" or "".join(new_wrd) == "Ms"
                    or "".join(new_wrd) == "Dr" or "".join(new_wrd) == "Jr"):

                    new_wrd.append(char)

                else:
                    if text[index+2].isupper():
                        new_line.append("".join(new_wrd))
                        new_line.append(char)
                        new_txt.append("".join(new_line))
                        new_line = []
                        new_wrd = []

                    else:
                        new_line.append("".join(new_wrd))
                        new_line.append(char + " ")
                        new_wrd = []

            else:
                new_wrd.append(char)

        elif char == " ":
            if ("".join(new_wrd) == "Mrs." or "".join(new_wrd) == "Mr." or "".join(new_wrd) == "Ms."
                or "".join(new_wrd) == "Dr." or "".join(new_wrd) == "Jr.") or new_wrd != []:

                new_line.append("".join(new_wrd))
                new_line.append(" ")
                new_wrd = []

        else:
            new_wrd.append(char)

    text = txt_file.readline()

for txt in new_txt:
    print txt
    txt_file.write(txt)
```

For the given example:

*Mr. XYZ is a good boy. He has just pass his B.Tech degree from ABC, Lmnop... At least, he has passed the degree.*

The output should show:

Mr. XYZ is a good boy.

He has just pass his B.Tech degree from ABC, Lmnop...

At least, he has passed the degree.

But instead, it shows:

*Mr. XYZ is a good boy.
He has just pass his B.Tech degree from ABC, Lmnop...*

What are the corrections that could be made for proper output?

Also, the the code:

```
txt_file.write(txt)
```

not working. Why?

Comment: You should not use `index+1` since you don't know if it exist! Especially when your code reach the ending text "`degree.`" there is nothing after the '.' (dot char)

Comment: Concerning the writing problem please be aware that you must open the file in _writting_ mode! ie. passing `w` as parameter of [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function.

Comment: I feel like you should be able to do this with regular expressions (including negative lookahead assertions)